# How to customize the Eclipse toolbars (Kepler or in general)

Tags: eclipse, toolbar

I've been trying to customize the toolbars in Eclipse (Kepler, JavaEE) for quite some time now.  After finally getting the toolbar configured the way I want in a given perspective (say, the main JavaEE perspective), when I switch to a different perspective (say, the Debug perspective) and then switch back, it's completely messed up.  Additionally, if at that point, I re-open the dialog to re-configure the toolbar again, I find that it's no longer in sync with the current state of the toolbar.

I've also tried saving my configurations as a custom perspective, with no effect (still does the same thing).

Overall, it seems that this aspect of the Eclipse IDE is almost completely broken.  I'm currently on a completely updated version, but this has been the case for a while, and I've seen it happen in many previous versions.

I would *LOVE* to be wrong about this.  Is there a way to be able to properly configure the toolbars in Eclipse? (and have it stay that way)

Comment: I generally just make my changes and save the perspective to the current name.  It prompts whether to overwrite the existing perspective, which I respond Yes.  This seems to work pretty well because you can always 'reset' the perspective back to the default if something happens.

Comment: Still does the same thing when I do that.

Comment: Sorry can't be more help - hitting Customize Perspective on my Kepler is giving me an NPE.  :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=420956).  It looks like it should be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Unfortunately this bug is not fixed in recently released Luna as well.

Comment: As much as I would love to state something better, toolbars where always a mess in Eclipse from 2.x on onwards. I guess they gave up on it back then... I typically somehow managed to get the three or four I really needed (typically the Debug/Run and the navigation arrows) to somehow appear and stay and doe what I want and just learned to ignore all others.

Answer (score 6):

This question was the first hit in my quest to find out how to customize the toolbar in Eclipse at all... so expecting others don't know the answer either it is:

(menu) ***Window*** > ***Customize Perspective***

from there one can manage toolbar and menu items.

Comment: is this wrong?  is it unhelpful?  So why the anonymous downvote?

Comment: I guess it may not have been answering the question? Anyway it answered what I wanted so thanks for the info!

Comment: works for me with `Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627`