# Eclipse Tool Bar Bug

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-luna

I customised the Eclipse tool bar by visiting `Window > Customize Perspective > Tool Bar Visibility.`

My customisation is automatically messed up in due course. When I try to re-customise, the `Tool Bar Visibility` window is not synchronised with the current status of the tool bar. This makes customisation is difficult and annoying.

I am using Kepler. The recently released Luna also have the similar behaviour. The Spring Tool Suite (which is basically Eclipse) also have the similar behaviour.

If this is an Eclipse bug, are there any workaround?

If this is not a bug, what am I missing?

[I am using Eclipse on OS X Mavericks]

Comment: You will have to be clearer about what you did and how exactly things get messed up. As it is, I have no idea what you are really having a problem with. So I can't answer the question.

Comment: Unfortunately thinks are not messed up in a consistent manner. Therefore it is not possible to tell how exactly the thinks are messed up.:-) If still not clear, open configuration window and check if that is in sync with the tool bar. (I only tested on OS X and Ubuntu but not on MS Windows)

Comment: After spending some time in Googling, I found the following question about the same problem (but unfortunately, this issue is not fixed in Luna as well): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654304/how-to-customize-the-eclipse-toolbars-kepler-or-in-general

Comment: After spending some more time on Eclipse, I found this website: http://www.ihateeclipse.com/. Now I understand that there are so many serious bugs in Eclipse. But it is surprising still many Java developers use Eclipse.

Comment: I wish I could help you, but I still don't really understand your problem. It could be that this is a bug, and you could try raising a bug report on bugs.eclipse.org, but I fear you won't get much help there either unless you can explain the problem more clearly. Don't get me wrong, it is possible to create bug reports about behavior that doesn't *always* happen consistently, but you still have to try and pin down something that goes wrong precisely, even if happens only every so often. Bug reports that are too 'fuzzy'... there's not much one can do, and so.. nothing happens.

Comment: BTW: I did try to customize the 'toolbar visibility' and as far as I can tell this is working fine for me. (STS 3.6.0 on Eclipse 4.4, Linux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After making extensive Googling, talking to my colleges and based on my own experience, I came to the following conclusion:

Eclipse has lots and lots of bugs and does not seem to be in active development now. Bugs are filed and kept for a very long time without being fixed. For example **[THIS](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=58945) BUG IS THERE FOR MORE THAN TEN YEARS** and [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=420956) bug is there since 2013. Eclipse bug tracking system does not easily show the whole list of current bugs.

The following links are worth mentioning:

[How to customize the Eclipse toolbars (Kepler or in general)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654304/how-to-customize-the-eclipse-toolbars-kepler-or-in-general?lq=1)

[Things possible in IntelliJ that aren't possible in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239732/things-possible-in-intellij-that-arent-possible-in-eclipse?rq=1)

http://www.ihateeclipse.com/

http://sebastien-arbogast.com/2009/07/18/why-do-i-hate-eclipse/

http://techdetails.agwego.com/2007/02/23/121/comment-page-1/

http://alblue.bandlem.com/2006/02/eclipserant-10-things-i-hate-about.html#bugs

[Is Eclipse the best IDE for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152691/is-eclipse-the-best-ide-for-java)

Comment: "Eclipse [...] does not seem to be in active development now". This is plain wrong. Eclipse might be focusing more on new features rather than fixing old bugs, but development is surely active. This is not even an actual answer, just a rant. The only useful part of the answer is the 2013 bug report, but nobody will notice it since is well hidden in the rant; and the more-than-ten-years bug is not a real bug, but a feature request.